# Div that shrinks, then returns to size, then flips over jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

I am somewhat of a jQuery noob. I am looking to have a `div` that, when clicked (or a button within that `div`) will first shrink width and height about 10px or so, then return to normal size, then flip over. I want it to flip back and forth with this animation with each click.

I have this so far:

jQuery:

```
$('.card').click(function(){
     $('.card').toggleClass('flipped');
    var div = $('.front , .back');
    div.animate({ width: '-=10px', height: '-=10px' });
    div.animate({ width: '+=10px', height: '+=10px' });

});
```

CSS:

```
 .container {
    width: 200px;
    height: 260px;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    -webkit-perspective: 800px;
    -moz-perspective: 800px;
    -o-perspective: 800px;
    perspective: 800px;
    }
   .card {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s;
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform 1s;
    -o-transition: -o-transform 1s;
    transition: transform 1s;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}
.card div {
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    line-height: 260px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 140px;
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.card .front {
  background: red;
}
.card .back {
    background: blue;
    -webkit-transform: rotateY( 180deg );
    -moz-transform: rotateY( 180deg );
    -o-transform: rotateY( 180deg );
    transform: rotateY( 180deg );
}
.card.flipped {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY( 180deg );
    -moz-transform: rotateY( 180deg );
    -o-transform: rotateY( 180deg );
    transform: rotateY( 180deg );
}
```

HTML:

```
<section class="container">
<div class="card" >
    <div class="front">THIS</div>
    <div class="back">THAT</div>
</div>
</section>
```

This works to flip the card, but it just subtracts the 10px and doesn't add it back properly. If I remove `$('.card').toggleClass('flipped');` it will shrink and grow perfectly, and if I remove

```
var div = $('.front , .back');
        div.animate({ width: '-=10px', height: '-=10px' });
        div.animate({ width: '+=10px', height: '+=10px' });
```

It flips perfectly. I just can't seem to get them to work together!

Here's a JSFiddle of what I have: https://jsfiddle.net/PistonLegs/qcvss2oj/1/
You can see in the fiddle, the height grows and the width shrinks. Not sure why.

Thanks, guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to animate the front and back separately, and you can pick which side to animate based off of the `flipped` state, then flip as a callback of the last animation.

```js
$('.card').click(function() {
  var div,
    anim = {
      top: '+=10px',
      bottom: '+=10px',
      left: '+=10px',
      right: '+=10px'
    },
    anim2 = {
      top: '-=10px',
      bottom: '-=10px',
      left: '-=10px',
      right: '-=10px'
    },
    speed = 500;
  if ($(this).hasClass('flipped')) {
    div = $('.back');
  } else {
    div = $('.front');
  }
  div.animate(anim,speed);
  div.animate(anim2,speed,function() {
    $('.card').toggleClass('flipped');
  });
});
```

```css
.container {
    width: 200px;
    height: 260px;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    -webkit-perspective: 800px;
    -moz-perspective: 800px;
    -o-perspective: 800px;
    perspective: 800px;
}
.card {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s;
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform 1s;
    -o-transition: -o-transform 1s;
    transition: transform 1s;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}
.card div {
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    line-height: 260px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 140px;
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.card .front {
  background: red;
}
.card .back {
    background: blue;
    -webkit-transform: rotateY( 180deg );
    -moz-transform: rotateY( 180deg );
    -o-transform: rotateY( 180deg );
    transform: rotateY( 180deg );
}
.card.flipped {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY( 180deg );
    -moz-transform: rotateY( 180deg );
    -o-transform: rotateY( 180deg );
    transform: rotateY( 180deg );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="container">
<div class="card" >
 <div class="front">THIS</div>
 <div class="back">THAT</div>
</div>
</section>
```

Comment: This is super close!! Some questions though. I notice in your snippet the font side shrinks from bottom right corner and then the back side shrinks from bottom left corner. Is there a way for the shrinking to happen from the center? I need it to look like the whole thing got smaller. Also, I need it all to happen a lot faster. Thanks so much!

Comment: @NickTaylor none of this is in your OP, and to avoid us going back and forth in the comments, please put your end goal clearly in your post. It's generally advised you have 1 clear question/problem per post, and if you learn you need help with additional stuff, make a new post instead of changing/adding to what you want in the current post.

Comment: Sorry about that! I thought I was clear with my op. It's kind of a hard thing to describe. But if you are consider my need to have the shrinking come from the center and the speed of the animation as a separate issue/question then I suppose I do need a new post.

Comment: Thanks so much! I actually found this which works perfectly!
http://jsfiddle.net/yQtwy/

Answer (score 0):

You need to separate these objects:

```
$('.card').click(function(){
         $('.card').toggleClass('flipped');
        $('.front').animate({ width: '-=10px', height: '-=10px' });
        $('.back').animate({ width: '+=10px', height: '+=10px' });

    });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/banzay52/pz3v213a/

Comment: This is close, but I need both the front and the back to shrink, then grow, then flip over. In your fiddle, every time I click the front gets bigger and the back gets smaller. I need each thing to happen once, each click. So one click would cause shrink, then return to size, then flip.